# Import vs Require in Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

While I was going through Angular2 documentation, I came across below code in [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html).

src/polyfills.ts

```
import 'core-js/es6';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
require('zone.js/dist/zone');

if (process.env.ENV === 'production') {
 // Production
} else {
 // Development
Error['stackTraceLimit'] = Infinity;
require('zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone');
}
```

In the above code we can see that there are both `import` and `require` statements.

"core-js" and "zone.js" are both node modules.

My question is; why is `import` used for core-js and `require` for "zone.js", is there any specific reason for this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

With TypeScript, `import` can be used if there is a declaration file (see [Declaration Files in basarat's book](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/ambient/d.ts.html)) for the module.

If there isn't a declaration file, the TypeScript compiler doesn't know if the module exists, so you need to use `require` instead which lacks the compilation checking.

Comment: I am not sure if that is correct , because I observed that for "core-js/es7/reflect" , only .js file exists , there is no .ts or .d.ts file

Comment: On the link you provided, right at the top, look in the "typings.json" section. The typings for core-js have been included, which will give the .d.ts files :)

Comment: zone.js does now include a .d.ts file and can be imported using `import`

Comment: Is there a way to make visual studio go for import->from over require? alt+enter always performs require

Comment: The link is broken. https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/intro/d.ts ?