# Jimp: image processing fail on module usage

Tags: javascript, angular, image, typescript

I am unable to use [Jimp](https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp).

installed: `npm install --save jimp` //OK

imported: `import * as Jimp from 'jimp';` //OK

usage `Jimp.read(someImage)` //fail with error

`Uncaught (in promise): Error: Node's Buffer() not available`

Comment: This seems to be a [bug in jimp](https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp/issues/280). A quick read tells me the only available solution right now is to lock your jimp version to 0.2.27 or earlier, as it is a regression. I haven't tried this, though. edit: Clarification: Might not be a bug, but rather an intended change oddly introduced in a patch.

Comment: i did try version 0.2.27 i had an error `Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Jimp.read is not a function`

Comment: Something you haven't posted must be going wrong. I just put jimp@0.2.27 in my application, imported in in the browser as you are, and `console.log(Jimp.read)` and got a function back.

Comment: i tried console.log(Jimp) got {} empty object. how do u import it. 
`import * as Jimp from 'jimp';`

Comment: I'm using `import * as Jimp from 'jimp'` and that's working fine. I'm using webpack, but it should not be different in TypeScript/Angular. What happens if you try `require('jimp')`? You might also try `import Jimp from 'jimp'`, which may work because Jimp is exported as CommonJS. I believe either should work.

Comment: `const Jimp = require('jimp');` importing it this way worked for me. can u give a good explanation in the answer section why this works. thankyou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a breaking change in Jimp 0.2.28, and the current solution is to revert to 0.2.27. However, as you've noted in the comments, `import` will not work for Jimp@0.2.27 for TypeScript.

It looks like with TypeScript, `require` and `import` accomplish two different things. So with `import`, you need to have a declaration file declaring the module so it can determine what the module is at compile-time. If you don't have that, TypeScript will not be able to resolve it at all. `require` happens at runtime, so TypeScript is uninvolved (and you won't have type information with `require`d modules).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39658366/1129436) explains it better than I could.

It looks like Jimp 0.2.27 does not define a `.d.ts` file while 0.2.28 does. I'm unsure why they included so many changes in one patch.

Answer (score 0):

Get the compiler error, when doing `import * as Jimp from 'jimp';`.
Turns out `Jimp`'s @type file uses `export =` [syntax](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html), So have to import like below:

> import Jimp = require('jimp');

Answer (score -1):

In a nodeJS environment and a pure `.js` file you can do:

```
import * as JimpObj from 'jimp';

const Jimp = JimpObj.default;


async function analizeImages() {
    const image = await Jimp.read(`image.png`);
    console.dir(image.bitmap.data);
}
```